# Returning an unknown object

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism

As an example, I have a base class called baseAbstractClass and a couple of derived classes:

```
public class Derived : baseAbstractClass
{
    public Derived()
    {
    }
    // abstract methods go here
}
public class DerivedEx : baseAbstractClass
{
   // code goes here
}
```

and I have this class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public SomeClass()
     {
     }
     object ReturnMeAnObject(int whichObject)
     {
          object toReturn = null;

          if (whichObject == 0)
          {
              toReturn = new Derived();
          }
          else
          if (whichObject == 1)
          {
               toReturn = new DerivedEx();
          }
          return toReturn;
     }
 }
```

In my Main function:

```
public class Start
{
     static void Main()
     {
          SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass()
          Derived derived = (Derived)someClass.ReturnMeAnObject(0);
     }
}
```

The object that I'm returning is unknown until runtime, but in reality I don't know the type of object is going to be returned - It could be Derived, or DerivedEx.
Is there a simplier way than having to cast my return value as shown in the Main function as this can result in a very large switch statement or, a very large set of If... Else conditions.

I have tried to determine if my design is correct by constructing a class diagram, but can't seem to fit it into code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might use interfaces....

Comment: Just declare the return type of `ReturnMeAnObject` to be `BaseAbstractClass`

Comment: You may consider to create a factory for instantaiting your objects based on a set of params. The returned objects all implement one interface that you can use. Why do you need the exact type? Or simply let the ReturnMeAnObject-method return BaseAbstractClass

Comment: You can use always assign a child class object to a parent class object, therefore  declare a parent class object and assign it  resulted object. you would need no parsing

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Won´t work because DerivedEx is not child-class of Derived but of BaseAbstractClass

Comment: How about using generics?

Comment: Do you know about all of `baseAbstractClass` descendants? Will the list of them be large enough? Is there any requirements for ability to dynamically add new descendant without modification of core code (e.g., via plugin mechanism)?

Comment: Can you share code what you would be doing on the main with the derived classes?

Comment: @Dennis I want to provide a method that produces different types of objects depending on, say, a menu item being selected.  How the menu is handled is going to be the same, but what what object type is returned is dependant on waht is selected.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @yorkshireflatcap: who builds the menu? Is this your code, or this is plugin-based application, and plugins can add menu items dynamically?

Comment: @Dennis how the menu is created is of no consequence as this is automation code.  I click on an item and I return an object appropriate to the menu item being clicked.  At the moment, the generics solution looks like a good idea since it does nicely what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved using generics. You have to limit the generic parameter `T` and ensure that the class that is used has a default constructor.

```
public T ReturnMeAnObject<T>() where T : baseAbstractClass, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Then you can use this in your code as follows:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass()
Derived derived = someClass.ReturnMeAnObject<Derived>();
DerivedEx derivedEx = someClass.ReturnMeAnObject<DerivedEx>();
```

Comment: He said that the until runtime he don't know which object would be returned. So your example does not meet the requirements, because he does not know what will get.

Comment: When he passes `0` as parameter then he already knows that he want to return an object of type `Derived`

Comment: Yes, but that value might come from the UI and thus runtime, your solution needs the value at compile time. Thus downvote.

Comment: Ok my mistake. In that case, the question is badly worded. Your solution looks correct for his requirements (because of this if statement). I changed my downvote to upvote

Comment: You may as well just do `Derived derived = new Derived()` and `DerivedEx derivedEx = new derivedEx()`

Comment: @xxMUROxx: I'd not bring generics into code without necessity. Your code is OK, but it makes sense only if the rest of code works differently with `Derived` and `DerivedEx`. I think, this isn't true.

Comment: I don't understand how this perfectly reasonable answer has been downvoted.  This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Coming from a C++ background, this is like using the dynamic_cast function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Polymorphism here and return base class `object` :

```
baseAbstractClass ReturnMeAnObject(int whichObject)
{
   baseAbstractClass toReturn = null;

   if (whichObject == 0)
   {
       toReturn = new Derived();
   }
   else
   if (whichObject == 1)
   {
       toReturn = new DerivedEx();
   }
   return toReturn;
}
```

and you can test it :

```
 SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
 var derived = someClass.ReturnMeAnObject(0);
 var DerviedTyped = Convert.ChangeType(derived,derived.GetType());
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WghCjJ)

### UPDATE:

you can cast it dynamically using [**`Convert.ChangeType()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
 SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
var derived = someClass.ReturnMeAnObject(0);
var derviedTypedObject = Convert.ChangeType(derived,derived.GetType());
```

Comment: Correct, but dont return `Derived`, return `baseAbstractClass` instead.

Comment: you need to cast to specific type by checking the type of object

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` doesn't work like that. At worst it will throw an exception; at best it will do nothing except make your `var` an `object` rather than anything useful.

Comment: @Rawling i have tested it in fiddle

Comment: Yup, I edited my comment. `Convert.ChangeType(derived,derived.GetType())` will return `derived` unchanged, but as an `object` so you come away with less strong typing than you had before.

Comment: @Rawling if i dont use ``ChangeType``, then i would have to do: ``if (derived is Derived) {  var DerivedTypeObject = derived as Derived }`` right?

Comment: At the moment, your `var derived` is `baseAbstractClass` at compile time and your `var derviedTypeObject` is `object` at compile time. `ChangeType` doesn't magically change the compile-time type of its return based on the runtime-type you pass in as a second arguments. Yes, checking the runtime type with `is` and casting is the only way you can get a compile-time type of `Derived` out of a compile-time type of `baseAbstractClass` (or `object`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Reflection class. like:

```
        object derived = someClass.ReturnMeAnObject(0);
        Type t = derived.GetType();
        switch (t.Name)
        {
            case "Derived":
                //do something
                break;
            case "DerivedEx":
                //do something
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid